# How can i read a python dict contained in a csv file and store the data in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have a csv where each row is a dictionary, inside each row's dict, there is a list, and this list contains a sublist and a subdict. Each sublist has 2 elements, and the subdict has 100 keys, and a value per key. This is a screenshot of the data:

[image]

Here's a sample of the data in text format:

```
{"0": [[10.8, 36.0], {"0": 0, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0}]}
{"1": [[10.8, 36.1], {"0": 0, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0}]}
{"2": [[10.8, 36.2], {"0": 0, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0}]}
{"3": [[10.8, 36.300000000000004], {"0": 0, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0}]}
{"4": [[10.8, 36.4], {"0": 0, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0}]}
{"5": [[10.8, 36.5], {"0": 0, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0}]}
{"6": [[10.8, 36.6], {"0": 0, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0}]}
{"7": [[10.8, 36.7], {"0": 0, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0}]}
{"8": [[10.8, 36.800000000000004], {"0": 0, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0}]}
{"9": [[10.8, 36.9], {"0": 0, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0}]}
```

What i would like to do is to read this into a pandas dataframe that would produce an expected output like this (i will just type a single row for the sake of simplicity):

```
list_elemnt_1   list_elemnt_2  key_0,  key_1,  key_2,  key_3,  key_4,  and so on...
        value           value  value   value   value   value   value   and so on...
```

For each row in the csv, i would like to build a dataframe with one column per sublist value (2), and one column for each key in the subdict contained on the row's dict.

How could i do this?? Please feel free to ask more information if needed.

Thank you very much in advance

**EDIT**

Key_0, key_1, key_2, etc... are the subdict keys, not the master dict keys

Comment: are you sure your provided data is correct? the first parenthesis and first bracket aren't closed

Comment: the `key_0` is which value? the master dict key or the sub dict key?

Comment: @zero excuse me, is fixed now

Comment: @Sid key 0 is the subdict key

Comment: every line looks like JSON data so you can read every line as normal text and convert to Python's dictionary `data = json.loads(line_from_file)` and then you can work with dictionary.

Comment: @furas mmm, this file was not really generated as a json file, but as a dict, anyway it may be ok what you say, i'll give it a try

Comment: how about renaming the file to .json? how does that foes for you?

Comment: @furas you perhaps wanna do `json.load` for file stream?

Comment: @P.hunter no, I want to read line manually and use single line in `json.loads` because file is not correctly formated JSON. It looks like multiple-JSON file - I don't know if `json.load` can work with multiple-JSON file. Only single lines are correctly formatted JSON.

Comment: the json trick does not work. I'm getting this error: `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'OrderedDict'`

Comment: @furas reading single lines won't work either. I used the following code: `with open('spe-list.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        json.loads(row)`

Comment: if you have `'OrderedDict'` then you don't need to use JSON. Use this dictionary to create row in dataframe. But it may need manually work.

Comment: I said: read as normal text - it means `open(filename).readlines()`

Comment: @furas `loads` and `load` has nothing to do with formatting, it's about passing the file stream of the content of file itself, but as you stated `json.loads(line_from_file)`, i believe you mean to do, `open('file_name.json', 'r').readline()` and then iterate over it, and then parsing it to json.

in that case `json.loads()` will work.

Comment: @P.hunter yes I mean `open().readline()` - and this is why I used name `line_from_file`, not `full_file` or `all_text_from_file`. And I do it only because of formatting in file in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

file = open('file_55966371.csv', 'r')

lines = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in file]

def clean_lines(line):
    value = [v for v in line.values()]

    l1, l2 = value[0][0]

    line_dict = value[0][1]

    line_dict = {f'key_{key}': value for key, value in line_dict.items()}

    line_dict['list_element1'] = l1
    line_dict['list_element2'] = l2

    return line_dict

to_read = [clean_lines(line) for line in lines]

df = pd.DataFrame(to_read)
```

I agree with @furas this looks a lot like a JSON, and if this data was sourced from someone, it would be best if you could ask them if they could send it to you in JSON format.

If not, the code above works.

- Open the file.
- read each line and store it as a list. `ast.literal_eval` allows Python to recognize that it's a dictionary from the get-go and stores them as `dict` objects.
- i created a helper `clean_lines` function. clean_lines is the more important part.

  1. get the values (i.e. the list with a sublist and a subdict)
  2. unpack the list into two variables `l1` and `l2`
  3. rename the key for the subdict (to your specs of `key_X`)
     d. add l1 and l2 as entries into the dictionary, basically combining the sublist and subdict into a single dictionary

Once you have a list of dictionaries, pandas will be able to recognize it and you can plug it into a `pd.DataFrame` instantiator object

Comment: yes please, some explanation about what's this piece of code doing would be really helpful for the sake of learning

Comment: Wow, that really looks like a very efficient approach. I would have never thought about it. I'm trying it out, i guess it will take a bit of time since the csv file is about 700 mb. I'll let you know how good is the output. Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: if it's 700 mb, I really think you should really ask if it could be sent as a JSON. that would make your life 1000x easier

Comment: yes maybe you are right. This file was the output of a really really  complex process with huge computations and it took us a lot of time to get it. Outputting this a json would take some changes in the code that produces this file. I will check if is possible, but if this work, we will just leave it like this by now

Comment: Buddy that does exaclty what i needed, i can't thank you enough, seriously. ypou saved me. And it didn't take that bunch of time, i think it took like 2 minutes more or less. Very handy what you did in your solution. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way to do it.

```
# Edit for reading the csv

# there are two ways to go about it, I am assuming data is in 1 column
df_csv = pd.read_csv('/path/to/your/file/filename.csv')


# read in the csv, I assume you are able to do this.
list_of_dfs = []
for idx, row in df_csv.iterrows():
      d = row[column_name]   # find the column name and insert here
      df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index') # creating a dataframe to get the number of lines

     remove_cols = df.columns

    for i in d.keys():
         df['list_elemnt_1'] = d[i][0][0]
         df['list_elemnt_2'] = d[i][0][1]
         for key in d[i][1].keys():
               df[key] = d[i][1][key]

         # remove the original cols here
         list_of_dfs.append(df)
```

This will give you the `df`s of each line as a line elemnt in the `list_of_dfs` which I assumed is the goal?
Let me know if it works.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But how would you read the csv? using open(csv).readlines()?? or how? because i see here you directly copy pasted a line and stored it in a variable, but that won't be the real use case

Comment: @Miguel2488 is it a single column in csv?

Comment: Thank you very much!! let me check it out :)

Comment: If you run into an issue regarding type of `d` change the line to `d = dict(row[column_name])`

Comment: thank you. I'm getting this error here: `XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'{"0": [['`

Comment: Were you able to read in the file earlier? `b'` means its in bytes format. I would suggest opening a new question for this. Try `pd.read_csv`

Comment: Allright dont worry. Thank you very much again for your help!!